# Merge function not copying into the vector correctly

Tags: c++, vector, merge, iterator, mergesort

The `merge(iterator, iterator, iterator2, iterator2, outIterator)` should take in 5 iterators, split up the vector sent in, then sort the 2 separate vectors, then merge them together into one sorted vector. My method seems to work unless `range2` has elements that are less than `range1` which will then fail my test.

```
template<typename Iter1, typename Iter2, typename OIter>
OIter merge(Iter1 first1, Iter1 last1, Iter2 first2, Iter2 last2, OIter out) {
   // TODO
   auto i = first1;
   auto j = first2;
   while (j != last2 && i != last1) {
       if (first2 == last2) {
           return std::copy(first1, last1, out);
       }
       if (*i < *j) {
           *out++ = *i++;  
       } else {
           *out++ = *j++;
       }
   }
   //only one of the ranges has elements copy them over
   if (first2 == last2) {
       return std::copy(first1, last1, out);
   } else {
       return std::copy(first2, last2, out);
   }
}
```

TEST:

```
REQUIRE( out == copy_out )
```

with expansion:

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } = actual
```

==

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 } = expected
```

Answer (score 1):

This logic is wrong

```
//only one of the ranges has elements copy them over
if(first2 == last2)
{
  return std::copy(first1, last1, out);
}else{
  return std::copy(first2, last2, out);
}
```

it should be

```
//only one of the ranges has elements left, copy them over
if(j == last2)
{
  return std::copy(i, last1, out);
}else{
  return std::copy(j, last2, out);
}
```

Also this special treatment

```
if(first2 == last2)
{
  return std::copy(first1, last1, out);
}
```

is unnecessary (and misplaced).